# Настройка CI/CD runner в Gitlab для автоматического тестирования при комите C#

Tags: c#, gitlab, ci-cd

Всем привет. Прошу помощи. Уже неделю разбираюсь с возможностью настройки автоматического юнит-тестирования при комите решений на C#. Все что я понял - это необходимо иметь проект и юнит-тесты под него, батник для запуска тестов. Каким образом настроить гитлаб, чтобы при комите запускались тесты и их результаты выводились в pipeline?

Comment: Проект есть? Юнит-тесты написаны и локально запускали? Проект на гитлабе уже собирается?

Comment: Проект есть, юнит-тесты написаны, локально запускал, батник для запусков тестов так же есть

Answer (score 1):

гитлаб сам по себе ничего не делает.

Чтобы сделать то, что вам нужно, вам нужна связка GitLab + Gitlab-runner.

Gitlab-runner - это среда исполнения сборочных линий или отдельных этапов этих линий, как сконфигурируете.

Соответственно, чтобы заработала сборочная линия, в настройках проекта у вас должен быть хотя бы один раннер, который будет обрабатывать сборочную линию. Как установить его, читайте тут [Install gitlab runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/)

Затем, вам нужна сборочная линия, которая конфигурируется в файле .gitlab-ci.yml. Что можно прописать в этом файлике можно почитать тут: [GitLab CI/CD pipeline configuration reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/)

Моя лень сегодня победила и я не доделал публикацию проекта на IIS, но вот пример построения проекта при любом коммите (актуально для мерджей - провалилась линия, мердж не пройдет) и сборка релиза для публикации:

```
    stages:
  - build
  - deploy
  
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    dotnet build project.sln
    
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    dotnet build project.sln -c Release
  only:
    refs:
      - master
  environment: production
```

Запустить тесты можно командой

```
dotnet test
```

или

```
mstest /testcontainer:testdllname.dll
```

А поскольку, вы не указали какие именно у вас тесты, MS Unit Test, XUnit, NUnit то предметно разбираться в нюансах придется вам самим, но в целом результаты выводятся как в консоль - вы увидите это в логах линии, так и в файлы - можно поместить в артефакты и хранить хоть вечно.

Обратите внимание, что не тэгированные линии обычно не запускаются - нужно в настройках раннера, привязанного к проекту галочку поставить, либо в yml файле теги раннера указать. Это сделано специально, так как у вас может быть сконфигурирован кластер с кучей различных раннеров под разные среды, тэги помогают определить который будет выполнять вашу сборочную линию.

Comment: Спасибо, а runner можно устанавливать на комп, с которого комитится решение?

Comment: Да, у меня так один установлен. Исполняемая среда shell. Но есть нюанс - во-первых это будет PowerShell, во вторых будут ограничения по загрузке уже установленных модулей в профиль пользователя. У меня, например, после установки SharePoint PnP Powershell по умолчанию (в профиль) - раннер не видел этот модуль.

Comment: Можно пример настройки .gitlab-ci.yml для работы с PowerShell?

Comment: Выше я вам привел весь ямл, где есть команды dotnet build - вот эти команды в шелле и выполняются. Туда можно и чистый PoSh писать. Почитайте внимательно описание разметки ямл и того, как раннер обрабатывает переменные среды PoSh и переменные из настроек проекта. 
Вот тоже реальный пример, выполняется сборка spfx для SharePoint Online, затем загружается модуль и выполняется публикация пакета в облако в функции Posh:
script:
    - gulp package-solution --ship
    - echo "Add powershell module"
    - . .\Scripts\Deploy.ps1
    - echo $DeploySPOurl
    - UploadPnpApp($DeploySPOurl)